# Cross-account IAM roles giving Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am trying to move a file cross account, from bucket accountA to bucket accountB, I am getting following error

> An error occurred while calling o88.parquet. dt/output1/parquet/_temporary/0/: PUT 0-byte object on dt/output1/parquet/_temporary/0/: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: F99P5W0C8Q28BJ4R; S3 Extended Request ID: VpFGWR9JR7r2yae9v8ezB7HAgJu0uuwn4v3mBAG8CaaJ2q0+sOVFGdxsZ1GzMXhAifSCtdxJ0OM=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: VpFGWR9JR7r2yae9v8ezB7HAgJu0uuwn4v3mBAG8CaaJ2q0+sOVFGdxsZ1GzMXhAifSCtdxJ0OM=:AccessDenied

I have following setup at my end.

Account A has following role cross-accountA-sample-role with following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Trust Relationship in Account A role**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::{accountBId}:role/{accountBrole}"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Account B cross account role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::{accountAId}:role/{accountArole}"
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT** Account B Policies attached to role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:*",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-glue-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-glue-*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*aws-glue-*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::crawler-public*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-glue-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:/aws-glue/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "aws-glue-service-resource"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

pretty much redundant access but at this point I am not concerned about that anymore.

Comment: So, you have account B credentials, you're using them to assume a role in account A, and then using those credentials to attempt to pull the objects from account A to accountB? The credentials you use need to allow both GetObject from A and PutObject to B. The assumed role only has the former, if I understand your situation correctly.

Comment: @jarmod, Wouldnt assume role not be enough to pull objects from account A? If I give S3 full access to account B would that solve the problem?

Comment: You can also do this with a combination of source IAM policy and destination bucket policy. See if [How can I copy S3 objects from another AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/) helps.

Comment: When you assume a role, you get a dedicated set of credentials associated with that role. Those credentials don't also have the original permissions.

Comment: @jarmod, I will not have access to S3 in the Prod its gonna be a different account, and I think bucket policy will not b updated, what options would I have?

Comment: Assuming you want this copying to happen within S3 (and not via local disk on an EC2 instance or EMR cluster) then that's a single S3 API request and the credentials you use to make that API request need both GetObject from A and PutObject to B. Neither of the IAM roles you've shown have both. Can you create/modify an assumable role in account B that allows PutObject access for B and GetObject for A, then modify the source A bucket's policy to allow GetObject from the B role?

Comment: @jarmod: I have updated account B policies, I dont think Account B explicitly needs GetObject, the GetObject should be assumed from role in account A. I will still give it a shot but I dont think that is gonna help. Also allowing bucket's policy wont help me in this case, as I mention I dont have access to bucket in Prod and Bucket is already there, so no 1 is going there and editing bucket.

Comment: Which IAM Role are you using to perform the copy? When performing a copy from Bucket A (account A) to bucket B (account B) you will use a single IAM Role to access both buckets, and this role should have enough permissions to access both buckets.

Can you add the exact command you run, and before that the output of `aws sts get-caller-identity` (it doesn't contain sensitive info, you can remove Account ID and replace them by AccountA and AccountB for anonymity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my finding, maybe not an ideal solution, but this is what worked for me.

The catch was something in my opinion not well explained by AWS, if there is such an explanation I am unware of that. What worked for me was to create a policy which assumes role from account A, Now if you see my policy below I am assuming role from account A. My understanding was that once we assume the role we dont need to do anything much, there will be an API call(internal) that will access bucket for me coz role attached to my Glue Job is assuming Role from account A. Guess what, this assumption didn't work for me.

What I actually had to do more was to make **STS assume call from within my code as well**, which grants me temporary credentials, with temporary credentials I had to update underlying Hadoop configurations. NOTE as of now **IF** the Glue Job Role (in account B) dont have STS assume Role capability the glue job will fail. Thanks to this article [STS assume Role API](https://tmmr.uk/post/aws-glue-assume-temporary-credentials/), I was able to do Cross account S3 access. I hope this saves someone 1s time.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import boto3
   
sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
response = sts_connection.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::account_id_here:role/my_role_assumed_from_accountA', RoleSessionName='GlueTenantASession',DurationSeconds=3600)
credentials = response['Credentials']
   
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', credentials['AccessKeyId'])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', credentials['SecretAccessKey'])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.session.token', credentials['SessionToken'])
   
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
   
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)
   
# Script generated for node S3 bucket
data_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"multiline": False},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="parquet",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3a://path_to_bucket_in_other_account"]},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)
data_frame.show()
```

My Inline policy to assume role from account A

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:iam::account_id:role/my_role_assumed_from_accountA"
        }
    ]
}
```